# Best practice to add tables for model objects to officer/ReporteRs

Tags: r, officer

`flextable::body_add_flextable` enables inserting `flextable` to Word document created by `officer`. The examples included in the packages are for creating tables from data frames. My question is, what the best practice of creating tables from model objects (e.g. from `lm`)? It is possible to convert model objects to data frames with, for example, `broom::tidy`, but it supports limited types of models and it is messy to get it to do side-by-side models comparison, while packages like `texreg` and `stargazer` already have great support for this. Is there an efficient way to convert `texreg::htmlreg` (or `texreg::screereg`) outputs to a `flextable` and insert it into Word document? Or more generally, is there a way to insert html contents into a Word document via `officer`?

(I know it is possible to create/customize my own flextables with whatever information I want however I want it, but it seems a huge wasted effort to repeat the work packages like `texreg` have already done well.) Thanks!

For demo purpose, this is what I'm trying to get into a Word document:

```
library(texreg)
fit_m1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars)
fit_m2 <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl, data=mtcars)
screenreg(list(fit_m1, fit_m2))
htmlreg(list(fit_m1, fit_m2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is kind of a workaround, but as far as I know the package [huxtable](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/)  has a function [huxreg()](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/huxreg.html). You can convert the huxtable with `as_flextalbe()` or just use it within `FlexTable()`. Or use pixiedust you can output dataframes and these can be used in `vanilla.table()`, `FlexTable()`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the `huxtable` package. It seems to be a good workaround for now.